# Mapping $filter from oData parameter to linq Where

Tags: c#, linq, odata, infragistics, ignite-ui

I've got (what I think is a odata format) url like this:

```
http://localhost:2282/SSE.Web/History.cshtml?GetData=true&itemId=AKE-00129&pid=1&%24filter=indexof(ItemType%2C%27Attri%27)+ge+0&%24skip=0&%24top=50&%24inlinecount=allpages&_=1325589443808
```

what is interesting here is the $filter parameter. It has the format "indexof(ItemType,'Attri') ge 0"

The source is an grid (iggrid from infragistics) that is filtering on the ItemType column with text 'Attri'

My question is: Mapping the top and skip parameters was trivial, but how to do the filter. Do I need to parse it and build my own linq, or are there some other ways?

This is the code I have so far:

```
        var skip = int.Parse(Request["$Skip"]);
    var top = int.Parse(Request["$top"]);
    var filter = Request(["$filter"]);

    var db = Database.Open("SSEConnectionString");

    var entries = db.Query("select * from eHistory order by timestamp desc")
    Json.Write(new { results = entries.Where(????).Skip(skip).Take(top), totalRecCount = entries.Count() }, Response.Output);
```

Thanks for any help!

Larsi

Comment: Are you using WCF Data Services? That should take care of all of that for you. If not, give it a try.

Comment: No, I was just using the Database mini orm comming from WebMatrix. And I was hoping to avoid the WCF Data service. But thanks for the suggestion. It is probably the best option.

Comment: The thing is that later when you want to support $expand and $select as well it gets really complicated. And I also doubt that the Json.Write produces OData compliant payloads. Maybe it's not a goal for you, but if it is, it becomes a problem soon as well.

Comment: @VitekKarasMSFT good point! Agree I'll run into problems later. I'll go with the wcf data service.

Comment: I have a similar requirement. Surely there's a way to reuse WCF Data Service's mechanism that converts odata filters to LINQ queries. Clearly WCF Data Services can do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use following NuGet package to apply filter: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Community.OData.Linq

Code sample would be:

```
using System.Linq;
using Community.OData.Linq;

// dataSet in this example - any IQuerable<T> 
Sample[] filterResult = dataSet.OData().Filter("Id eq 2 or Name eq 'name3'").ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the MVC wrapper for the igGrid then the mapping is done for you.  The following is a quote from the [Infragistics jQuery help](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/NetAdvantage/jQuery/2011.2/CLR4.0/html/igGrid_Filtering.html):

> "When the ASP.NET MVC wrapper is used to bind to server-side data
>   through LINQ (IQueryable), all filtering information that’s encoded in
>   the URL is automatically translated to LINQ expression clauses (Where
>   clause), so you do not need to do anything additional in order to
>   filter the data."